# Как установить Docker на OS X Yosemite (10.10)

Tags: golang, docker, macos, homebrew

Пытался качать старые версии под Yosemite, но они при запуске отваливаются.
Начал ставить с помощью homebrew, там получаю ошибку

```
==> Installing dependencies for docker: go and go-md2man
go: macOS El Capitan or newer is required.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Последняя версия golang для Yosemite - 1.12, ее поставить получилось, однако, попытка поставить docker закончилась той же ошибкой.

```
iMac27-2 ~$ brew info go
go: stable 1.14.5, HEAD
Open source programming language to build simple/reliable/efficient software
https://golang.org
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/go.rb
License: BSD-3-Clause
==> Requirements
Required: macOS >= 10.11 ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 95,497 (30 days), 262,945 (90 days), 1,299,007 (365 days)
install-on-request: 78,643 (30 days), 214,033 (90 days), 1,031,655 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)


iMac27-2 ~$ brew info go@1.12
go@1.12: stable 1.12.17 [keg-only]
Go programming environment (1.12)
https://golang.org
/usr/local/Cellar/go@1.12/1.12.17 (9,630 files, 449MB) *
  Built from source on 2020-07-17 at 09:30:03
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/go@1.12.rb
License: BSD-3-Clause
==> Caveats
go@1.12 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.
==> Analytics
install: 790 (30 days), 2,886 (90 days), 30,056 (365 days)
install-on-request: 659 (30 days), 2,261 (90 days), 18,651 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)


iMac27-2 ~$ go version
go version go1.12.17 darwin/amd64
```

Вариантов решения два:

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, откуда скачать нормальную версию docker`а
2. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как homebrew указать, чтобы при установке докера он брал golang из уже установленной формулы

Comment: вы пытаетесь установить `docker-cli`, это всего программа для управления докером, но не больше, "полный" докер можно поставить `brew cask install docker`, но он работает только на mac os 10.13 и выше, поэтому скорее всего нужно ось обновлять или использовать Docker Toolbox

Comment: Ставьте Virtual Box туда Debian и в нем вертите контейнеры. VB хорошо поддерживается маками.